# После обновления пакетов Xorg не принимает настройки

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, xorg

К raspberry подключен tochscreen ([E17SAW6](http://www.espada-tech.ru/pr_-34408.shtml)) через USB, после калибровки (xinput_calibrator) он работал правильно, но после того как я  обновил мой raspbian:

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Он игнорирует калибровку, хотя она осталась как и была ([/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf](https://paste.ofcode.org/JkpugU3N8ytkbtTRukaKwA)), сенсор работает как изначально, до калибровки (в верхнем правом углу, пикселей 500x500, как будто маленький экран).
[В логе Xorg ошибок нету](https://paste.ofcode.org/NC8F3EV4WcWwzqQEyK2Jnp)
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Xorg создаёт файл 40-libinput.conf, который переопределяет устройства с другими драйверами (Driver "libinput"), а калибровка (в моём случаи), работает только с evdev (Driver "evdev"), настройка для evdev находятся в 10-evdev.conf ,то есть нужно удалить 40-libinput.conf из /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ и убедится что присутствует 10-evdev.conf

Файлы: https://yadi.sk/d/J_jQ1b2V3M9Y7b